# netbeans apache derby connection not working

Tags: java, netbeans, connection, derby

I am currently learning how to use the embedded Apache Derby database using Netbeans. I watched a tutorial on youtube to see how to connect to the database and I wrote the same code as the one in the tutorial did. My problem now is that i get an error message which says that it couldn't find the driver i think.

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

And here's my code:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contact", "nbuser", "nbuser");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs =  st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM APP.FRIENDS");
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();

        for(int i = 1; i != meta.getColumnCount(); i++){

            System.out.println(meta.getColumnName(i));

            while(rs.next()){

                for(int x = 1; x != meta.getColumnCount(); x++){
                    System.out.println(rs.getObject(x));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the [JDBC jar](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.11.1.1.cgi) in your classpath ?

Comment: I read that the database is installed with netbeans do I have to copy it in my classpath then?

Comment: I do not use netbeans so I would not know if it is in the classpath by default. My guess is that derby is embedded inside netbeans itself ? You would still need to copy the client JDBC jar and refer to that in your classpath (since it would be unreasonable for Netbeans to assume that derby would need to be placed in the classpath of *any* application launched inside NetBeans).

Comment: Ok I did have to put it in to the classpath. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've moved the answer from the comments to the `answers` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the JDBC jar for [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.11.1.1.cgi) into your classpath.